# The perl interpreter could not be found

Tags: latexdiff

I am new to LaTeX and using it for my thesis. However, right now I am having trouble in using `latexdiff`. I did the instructions as follows:

Question: How to generate `latexdiff` on Windows?

Answer:

1. Download and install ActivePerl?

   Assume you install ActivePerl? in `C:\Perl`
2. Download `latexdiff` perl script

   Assume you download `latexdiff` to `C:\temp`
3. The `latexdiff` script makes use of the Perl package `Algorithm::Diff`

   Unzip `Algorithm-Diff-1?.1902.tar.gz`, and then copy whole `Algorithm-Diff-1?.1902\lib\Algorithm` directory to `C:\perl\lib`
4. Assume you have a old LaTeX file name `old.tex` and a new LaTeX file named `new.tex` both located in `C:\temp`
5. Start a new command prompt, type `cd c:\temp` to change the current directory to `c:\temp`. Type `perl latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`, this will generate a new LaTeX file named `diff.tex` that contains the different between `old.tex` and `new.tex`

However, every time I typed `c:\temp\perl latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`, the system says "perl is not an internal or external file", every time I typed `c:\temp\latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`, it says "The perl interpreter could not be found." I have already checked the PATH variable, and it contains path to perl in `c:\perl64\bin`. What should I do next? I have exhausted every method but could not find a way.

Comment: If your Perl interpreter (perl.exe) is in C:\Perl, than your PATH should contain that, and not C:\perl64\bin.

Comment: You say that you typed `c:\temp\perl` but the instructions say to type `cd c:\temp`. This should be followed by pressing the Return/Enter key (implied in the instructions -- all commands need to be completed in that way). Then type `perl latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`. Since you don't have `perl.exe` in `c:\temp`, the OS would give "perl is not an internal or external file" if you do `c:\temp\perl`.